# Как победить искажение текста кирилицы в bash, запущенном в Docker-контейнере?

Tags: docker, кириллица, locale

Настроил локаль для контейнера:

```
# Set the russian locale
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8
```

При этом русский текст в bash терминале все-равно работает неправильно: ввод начинается с символа ":�", вставка текста на русском выгляди точно также (начало строки искажается при вставке). Как бы справиться с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример из рабочего Dockerfile, проверено и работает.

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales

# Locale
RUN sed -i -e \
  's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
   && locale-gen

ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU:ru
ENV LC_LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8

# +Timezone (если надо на этапе сборки)
ENV TZ Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Да, все получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

вероятно, в образе, используемом вами, не сгенерирована такая локаль (`ru_RU.UTF-8`).

посмотрите список командой `locale -a` (приведён пример вывода):

```
$ docker run --rm -ti имя-образа locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

для нормальной работы с кириллицей вполне подойдёт имеющаяся локаль `C.UTF-8`:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

---

если же необходима именно русскоязычная локаль, то её надо сгенерировать. наиболее, пожалуй, универсальный способ — использовать скрипт *locale-gen*:

```
$ locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

скрипт этот присутствует (в debian-основных дистрибутивах) в пакет `locales`, который в вашем образе, скорее всего, тоже отсутствует, и его надо установить.

демо-пример для проверки:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -e LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 ubuntu:16.04 bash -c 'apt update && apt install -y locales && locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8; bash'
```

Comment: Не помогло. Выполнилось без ошибок, но ввод кириллицы по-прежнему почти невозможен. Ошибки такие - ввод можно начать не с любой буквы, в начале вводимой строки подставляется символ (как в вопросе), ввод строки кириллицей "убивает" предыдущую часть строки..

Comment: значит, что-то делаете неправильно. дополните вопрос своей попыткой. образец: `$ docker run --rm -ti -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ubuntu:16.04 bash` // p.s. и уточните, нормально ли вводится кириллица напрямую (т.е., без запущенного docker-ом процесса) в эмуляторе терминала.

Comment: Сорри, я нуб в докере. Вот эта команда: "$ docker run --rm -ti -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ubuntu:16.04 bash" похоже просто скачала образ, результат вывелся такой: "Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:16.04"